How to get function address in indirect call
There is a sum function called inside the foo function. there is a scanner function to read the instructions in the foo function. when the scanner encounters the FF opcode, it goes to the operand register. How to get the function address from this register. or is there a different method?
briefly i want to detect if a specific function is called in the function passed to the scanner function. for example to detect if malloc is called in pf.
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//the function to call in foo
int sum(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}

//function pointer for absolute address
int(*funsum)(int, int) = sum;

//the function where funsum is called
void foo(){
    int result = funsum(1, 1);
}

//To read insturactions in foo
void scanner(void *pf){
    unsigned char *f = pf;
    while (*f != 0xc3)//the loop continues until ret is encountered
    {
        if(*f == 0xff){//call encountered
            unsigned char *reg = f + 1;
            //in here how can i access the address of funsum()
        }
        f++;
    }
}

int main(){
    scanner(foo);
}


It's unclear what you want. If it's in a register you can't access it statically. You will need to figure out how the register is loaded. Or use debugging features to examine the register at runtime. Alternatively, if you mean you need to figure out which register holds the address then consult the r/m field of the modrm byte. See also Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte in the instruction set reference.

I assume you're talking about shared libraries when you speak about indirect calls? If so, note that the address might not even be known if lazy binding is used.

@Jester I am trying to get the address of the function in the function call inside the pf function passed to the scanner function. shortly, trying to get the address of the called function.

You can't easily do that. You would need to decode the call to see which register is used and then scan the code backwards to maybe find a constant load to that register if you are lucky.

@kaan, your code is reading assembly code. The running code is yours and uses registers, but the read assembly code is an image. It will use register when running.

The indirect function call opcode gets the address from somewhere.  Analyse the code to find out where it comes from and retrieve the address from that memory.

Are you sure you want the address of global data pointer variable funsum or maybe you really want the value held by that pointer variable (e.g. address of sum), i.e. to call it?

@ErikEidt i want to detect if a specific function is called in the function passed to the scanner function. for example to detect if malloc is called in pf.

You want to detect if malloc is being called via function pointer?  In the most general case, that is a dynamic situation, as it could call something different each time not something you can decide statically, unless you know some constraints that restrict the problem to certain cases.

If the goal is to detect specific function, you can go by way of proxy functions. Just write a proxy for the function you want to detect. Add there a printout "I was called" and pass execution to real function.

When dealing with indirect function calls, the challenge is that the address of the CALL instruction is stored in a register, making it less straightforward to trace than a direct function call. Let's dive into how to handle this in your scanner function by examining the assembly code generated by your program.
Direct vs. Indirect Function Calls
In your program, a direct function call to scanner() in main is straightforward to trace. For example:
00000000000011a7 <main>:
    11a7:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    11ab:       55                      push   %rbp
    11ac:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    11af:       48 8d 05 8b ff ff ff    lea    -0x75(%rip),%rax        # 1141 <foo>
    11b6:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    11b9:       e8 a8 ff ff ff          call   1166 <scanner>

This directly references the address in the CALL instruction. However, in foo, the function call is indirect:
0000000000001141 <foo>:
    1141:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1145:       55                      push   %rbp
    1146:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1149:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
    114d:       48 8b 05 bc 2e 00 00    mov    0x2ebc(%rip),%rax        # 4010 <funsum>
           <some instructions omitted for clarity>
    115e:       ff d0                   call   *%rax

Here, the address is loaded into RAX before the CALL instruction. To trace this, you need to calculate the effective address of the function being called.
Modifying scanner to handle the indirect call
Here's how you can modify your scanner function to handle this:
void scanner(void *pf) {
    unsigned char *f = (unsigned char *)pf;
    uintptr_t address_in_rax = 0;

    while (*f != 0xc3) { // Loop continues until RET (0xC3) is encountered

        // Check for "MOV RAX, [RIP+offset]" instruction
        if (*f == 0x48 && *(f + 1) == 0x8b && *(f + 2) == 0x05) {
            // Calculate the offset (signed 32-bit value) from the next instruction
            int32_t offset = *(int32_t *)(f + 3);
            uintptr_t effective_address = (uintptr_t)(f + 7) + offset;

            // Dereference to get the address being loaded into RAX
            address_in_rax = *(uintptr_t *)effective_address;

            printf("Address loaded into RAX (funsum address): %p\n", (void *)address_in_rax);

            // Verify the address matches the actual function pointer
            if (address_in_rax == (uintptr_t)funsum) {
                printf("Verified: Address matches the funsum function pointer.\n");
            } else {
                printf("Warning: Address does not match the funsum function pointer!\n");
            }
        }

        // Check for "CALL RAX" instruction
        if (*f == 0xff && (*(f + 1) & 0xf8) == 0xd0) {
            printf("CALL instruction found. Address in RAX: %p\n", (void *)address_in_rax);
        }

        f++;
    }
}

This code checks for the specific instruction sequences that load an address into RAX and then calls it. It handles the case where the address is calculated relative to RIP. You can, of course, extend this further to match different cases.
Handling Optimizations
Keep in mind that compiler optimizations can alter how functions are called. For example, under different optimization levels (-O1, -O2, -O3), the function call in foo may be optimized away or replaced with different instructions (I checked this with gcc 11 for x64):
At -O1, the offset is calculated directly in the CALL instruction.
At -O2 and above, the function might be inlined or replaced with a JMP instruction.
To handle these cases, you might need to extend your scanner function further, but then you're effectively building a decompiler.
Back to your goal
Evidently, detecting whether a specific function is invoked, either directly or indirectly, can be quite challenging. Here are some approaches you might consider:
Using Debug Symbols: If the binary includes debug symbols, you can use a debugger like gdb to set breakpoints on the function of interest. This won't work if the function is optimized away or if the binary was compiled without debug symbols.
Interpreting the Assembly: If the function isn't directly traceable through debug symbols, you'll need to interpret the assembly code, as we discussed earlier. This involves manually tracing through the code, following register values, and understanding how function pointers are used. This process can become complex, especially in large programs or when advanced compiler optimizations are enabled.
Dealing with Obfuscation: If the binary has been intentionally obfuscated, detecting function invocations becomes significantly harder. Obfuscation techniques might disguise function calls, obscure control flow, or even modify the function itself. In such cases, standard debugging and static analysis tools might not be sufficient. Advanced reverse engineering techniques or specialized tools may be required to analyze the binary.
Binary Analysis Tools: There are tools specifically designed for static and dynamic binary analysis, such as Ghidra that can help with identifying function calls, even in optimized or obfuscated binaries. These tools can automate some of the manual work involved in interpreting assembly code, making it easier to identify whether a function is invoked.
There are many ways to Rome, so it all depends on where you are starting. Hope this helps and good luck!

Thanks you! it work but when foo modified it does not work. https://godbolt.org/z/hzbMTqr71

No problem! What did you modify? I expect that, for the most part, getting this to work will be a game of cat and mouse as you cover more and more cases.

i only changed foo function. and registers that function stored changed too. it does not always use same registers.
